# Use coinbase pro websockets with cpprestsdk

Tags: c++, websocket, coinbase-api, cpprest-sdk

I want to receive updates from websockets defined in the [coinbase pro API](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#sequence-numbers).

For example I'd like to register the heartbeat channel, that should be received once per second according to documentation.

I've tried to register to the web socket, but I obtain only the subscriptions message in reply:

```
{"type":"subscriptions","channels":[{"name":"heartbeat","product_ids":["ETH-EUR"]}]}
```

After that I'm not receiving anything anymore. What should I do in order to listen to the messages of the client

This is the piece of code involved (modified a bit, it's in a class, `m_webSocket` is a class member that should be used also elsewhere, and it should be closed in the destructor):

```
void EndpointClient::connectToWebSockets() {
  constexpr auto WebSocketFeed{ U("wss://ws-feed.pro.coinbase.com") };
  constexpr auto RequestStatus{ "{\"type\": \"subscribe\", \"channels\" : [{ \"name\": \"heartbeat\", \"product_ids\" : [\"ETH-EUR\"] }]}" };
  web::websockets::client::websocket_client m_webSocket;
  try {
    m_webSocket.connect(WebSocketFeed).wait();
    auto receivedTast = m_webSocket.receive().then([this](websocket_incoming_message ret_msg) {
      auto s = ret_msg.extract_string();
      m_logger->info("s = " + s.get());
      });

    websocket_outgoing_message msg;
    msg.set_utf8_message(RequestStatus);
    m_webSocket.send(msg).wait();
    receivedTast.wait();
    m_webSocket.close().wait();
  }
  catch (websocket_exception& e) {
    m_logger->error("coinbase: exception when setting websocket: " + string{ e.what() });
  }
  catch (std::exception& e) {
    m_logger->error("coinbase: exception when setting websocket: " + string{ e.what() });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.receive()` method only gets one message. If you want to receive more incoming messages, you need to run it in a loop. Or you can use a `websocket_callback_client` instead so that it can listen automatically (`websocket_callback_client.set_message_handler()` method).